# ActionBar title not changing

Tags: android, android-viewpager, title

I have implemented viewpager in a fragment activity. This fragment activity contains two swipe fragments. To set the title of fragments in the actionbar i have done this in the fragment activity.

```
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() 
    {
        public void onPageSelected(int position) 
        {

        //**this is line68 where error is occuring**       
       getActionBar().setTitle(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(position).toString());

                        }
```

But , I am not too sure how to set the title of two fragments. In fragments i've done this.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.patient_list, container, false);
        getActivity().setTitle("All Patients");
```

I got Nullpointerexception...

```
06-05 23:54:26.269: E/AndroidRuntime(6430): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-05 23:54:26.269: E/AndroidRuntime(6430): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-05 23:54:26.269: E/AndroidRuntime(6430):     at com.example.actionbar.MainActivity$1.onPageSelected(MainActivity.java:68)
06-05 23:54:26.269: E/AndroidRuntime(6430):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.scrollToItem(ViewPager.java:538)
06-05 23:54:26.269: E/AndroidRuntime(6430):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:523)
06-05 23:54:26.269: E/AndroidRuntime(6430):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:1943)
06-05 23:54:26.269: E/AndroidRuntime(6430):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7340)
06-05 23:54:26.269: E/AndroidRuntime(6430):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2181)
06-05 23:54:26.269: E/AndroidRuntime(6430):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1914)
06-05 23:54:26.269: E/AndroidRuntime(6430):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2187)
```

Please help.

Comment: You are going to need to determine which of those things is `null`: `getActionBar()`, `mAppSectionsPagerAdapter`, or `mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(position)`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your `mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(position)` returns `null`, so check if you overrided the method `getPageTitle` on your viewpager's `PagerAdapter`.

Comment: No i didnt override the getPageTitle method.

Comment: @user2343207 That's why you got a NullPointerException. You are trying to use null.toString().

Comment: Thnx a lot..but still the actionbar title is not changing as per the fragments. Its always taking the title of last fragment and also becoming blank when fragments are changed

Comment: @user2343207 Try to debug with a breakpoint in your `getPageTitle` method

Answer (score 0):

Line 68 has more than 1 possible null values. You should debug your code and evaluate each of the statements in that line to check for null (set breakpoint and check with inspect option for null).

<sup>Alternative option is to split up the line in multiple lines and run code again to check line number of error.</sup>